# How to update Source ID in ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add parameters into a ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add

I have managed to change all except the on in 'Source{[Id=""Table001""]}', inside the ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add

I have  tried Source{[Id=" & TableOnly & "]} but I get an error in line 'ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add': The import table Table001 matches no exports

See below the full code and where 'Source{[Id=""Table001""]}' is located

```
For i = 1 to 3

TableName = "Table00" & i & " (Page " & i + 2 & ")" 'Example: "Table001 (Page 3)"
DispName = "Table00" & i & "__Page_" & i + 2 & "" 'Example: "Table001__Page_3"
TableOnly = "Table00" & i 'Example: Table001

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=TableName, Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
    "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""C:\Sample.pdf""), [Implementation=""1.3""])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
    "    " & TableOnly & " = Source{[Id=""Table001""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
    "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(" & TableOnly & ",{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5"", " & _
    "type text}, {""Column6"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & TableName & ";Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & TableName & "]")
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SaveData = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = DispName
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had to add an addition inverted comas at each end as:

```
 Source{[Id=""" & TableOnly & """]}
```

Hope is helps someone.